Reformulating conditional expectation on pushforward measure
Under a given probability space with probability measure $P$, let's assume that the distribution $P^X$ of a random variable $X$ is known. I was just calculating a conditional expectation with respect to $P^X$, i.e. an expression of the following form
$$
\begin{aligned}
E_{P^X}[P^X(A|T)1_{T\in B}]&=E_{P^X}[1_A1_{T\in B}]\\
\end{aligned}$$
Now, I was wondering, if it is possible to reformulate this, in case you would prefer to calculate on the measure $P$ instead of $P^X$. I find
$$
\begin{aligned}
E_{P^X}[P^X(A|T)1_{T\in B}]=E_P[P(X\in A|T\circ X)1_{T\circ X\in B}]
\end{aligned}$$
Is this correct? I concluded like this:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E_{P^X}[P^X(A|T)1_{T\in B}]&=E_{P^X}[1_A1_{T\in B}]\\
&=E_P[1_{X\in A} 1_{X\in\{T\in B\}}]\\
&=E_P[1_{X\in A} 1_{T\circ X\in B}]\\
&=E_P[P(X\in A|T\circ X)1_{T\circ X\in B}]\\
\end{aligned}$$
Clarification: Note that if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is the probability space and $\mathcal{H}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra, you denote
$$P(A|\mathcal{H}):=E_P[1_A|\mathcal{H}]$$
for some $P$-measurable set $A$, i.e. $A\in\mathcal{F}$.
For a $P^X$-measurable set $A$ you find as pointed out in the answer below
$$P^X(A|T)\circ X=E_{P^X}[1_A|T]\circ X = E_P[1_A\circ X|T\circ X]=P(X\in A|T\circ X),$$
since $1_A\circ X = 1_{X\in A}$ and ${X\in A}$ is $P$-measurable. Integration with respect to the pushforward measure yields
$$E_{P^X}[P^X(A|T)1_{T\in B}]=E_P[P^X(A|T)\circ X 1_{T\circ X\in B}]=E_P[P(X\in A|T\circ X)1_{T\circ X\in B}]$$

What is $T$ ? $\phantom.$

$T$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

From the very scratch. Let
$$\tag1
\Omega \overset{X}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb R \overset{T}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb R
$$
be measurable where $\mathbb R$ has the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\cal B$ and $\Omega$ some other $\sigma$-algebra $\cal F$ on which we have the probability measure $\mathbb P\,.$ The distribution of $X$ (pushforward measure) is defined as
$$\tag2
\mathbb P_X(A)=\mathbb P\{X\in A\}\,,\quad A\in\cal B\,.
$$
Let $U:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be Borel measurable. The conditional expectation of $U$ w.r.t. $T$ under $\mathbb P_X$ is the
random variable $V=\mathbb E_X[\,U\,|\,T\,]$ that is $\sigma(T)$-measurable and satisfies
$$\tag3
\textstyle\int_AV\,d\mathbb P_X=\int_AU\,d\mathbb P_X
$$
for all $A\in\sigma(T)\,.$ Since
$$\tag4
\sigma(T)=\big\{T^{-1}(B):B\in\cal B\big\}
$$
and
$$\tag5
\int_AW\,d\mathbb P_X=\int_{X^{-1}(A)}W\circ X\,d\mathbb P
$$
we can write (3) as
$$\tag6
\int_{(T\circ X)^{-1}(B)}V\circ X\,d\mathbb P=\int_{(T\circ X)^{-1}(B)}U\circ X\,d\mathbb P\,.
$$
Let's denote by $\cal G$ the sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\cal F$ that is generated by $T\circ X\,.$ Obviously
$$\tag7
{\cal G}=\{(T\circ X)^{-1}(B):B\in\cal B\}\,.
$$
The RV $U\circ X$ is only $\cal F$-measurable but $V\circ X$ is $\cal G$-measurable. Thus, (6) shows that
$$\tag8
\mathbb E\big[U\circ X\big|{\cal G}\big]=V\circ X\,.
$$
Writing this out we have
$$\tag9
\mathbb E\big[U\circ X\,\big|\,T\circ X\big]=\mathbb E_X\big[\,U\,\big|\,T\,\big]\circ X\,.
$$

Many thanks for looking over it. I have the same result. Especially, the equality I was wondering about holds, since $E_P[E_X[U|T]\circ X 1_{(T\circ X)^{-1}(B)}]=E_X[E_X[U|T]1_{T^{-1}(B)}]$.
